# Could not connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'root'@'91.223.9.100' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, sql, web, upload

I am trying to upload a website i created a few months ago. when I run the website using my computer as the server it works as desired. Using XAMPP

However when I Upload it I am getting an the error:

```
 Could not connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'root'@'91.223.9.100' (using password: NO)
```

Can anyone help me with the origin of this error. the web pages not using the a sql database look ok.

This is the first time I have tried this so I am sure it is a very basic error on my behalf.

I used filezilla to transfer the files across, I changed localhost to the FTP Hostname in the connect.php. then I tried changing it to the server IP.

Comment: Is your MySQL server turned on? Is it listening on the correct port and address?

Comment: Did you try using the host `127.0.0.1` instead of `91.223.9.100` and `localhost`?

Comment: @ Saji just tried that with no luck. @Dharman how can I check if MySQL is turned on? what do you mean listening on correct port and address?

Comment: Check with your hosting provider what user name, password, and host name you're supposed to use for MySQL. Pretty sure have to use a password, and cannot use the root account.

Comment: @joni I have been supplied a username and password, I tried using instead of root bit access is still denied. Do I have to add these credentials to the SQL doc by any chance?

Comment: to wherever you set the database credentials in your scripts.